# Hide div onclick outside typescript, nextjs tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've a modal with typescript, next js and tailwindcss. I want to hide the modal when I click outside the modal. But I'm getting some type and other errors in tsx.

In jsx it works fine but in tsx its not working. I'll be very very thankful if anyone help me about this. Thanks in advance

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const Backdrop = (props) => {

    const ref = useRef();
    const { onClick, children } = props;

    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
        if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
            onClick && onClick();
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, true);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, true);
        };
    }, []);

    if (!children) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div ref={ref}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Backdrop;
```

Comment: What error you are getting and how it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

**create file `useIsClickOut.ts`**
**copy this code and paste**

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export const useIsClickOut = (setter: (bool: boolean) => void): [(node: any) => void] => {
    const [ele, setEle] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
    const eleCallback = useCallback((node: HTMLDivElement) => { 
setEle(node) }, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if (ele === null) return;

    const handleClick = (e: any) => {
        if (ele.contains(e.target)) return;
        setter(false)
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);
}, [ele]);

 return [eleCallback]
};

export default useIsClickOut;
```

**in your file this how to use it**

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
const [eleCallBack] = useIsClickOut(setOpen)
     
return !open ? null : (
   <div ref={eleCallBack}>
      {children}
   </div>
);
```